# Ruby on Rails AJAX checkbox inside AJAX search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

So I basically want the current_user to be able to blacklist users. So I created a search for the users and a form which gets the selected checkboxes and blacklists or whitelists them. The search is done through AJAX but the problem is that after the search is done the checkbox ( if checked ) becomes unchecked. How do I keep the checkbox value as it is:

Controller:

```
   def show
     @b_page = BPage.find(params[:id])
     if params[:search221]
       @users = User.search(params[:search221])
       respond_to do |format|
        format.js
       end
     else
      @users = User.all
     end
  end
```

Show Page:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal5541" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <h1> Privacy Settings</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= form_tag b_page_path, :method => 'get', :id => "users_search", :remote => true do %>
          <p>
          <%= text_field_tag :search221, params[:search221], class: 'form-control', autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Search for users'%>
          <div class="text-center">
             <%= submit_tag "Search", class:"btn btn-primary"%>
          </div>
        <% end %>

        <%= form_tag({:controller=>"b_pages",:action=>"change_privacy_settings"} , method: :put) do %>
             <ul id="yolo"> <%= render "losers"%> </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <%= submit_tag "Update Privacy Settings"%>
        <% end %>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

losers partial:

```
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <div id="<%= user.id%>">
       <div class="panel">
           <%= check_box_tag "user_ids[]", user.id%>
           <%= image_tag(user.avatar.url(:thumb))%>
          <%= user.username %>
       </div>
     </div>
  <% end %>      
   <div class="center">
       <%= will_paginate @users, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails  %>
   </div>
```

show.js.erb:

```
$("#yolo").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'losers', :locals => {:users=> @users}) %>")
```

How do I not loose the checkbox value(losers partial) even after the search?

Comment: your code seems have error.

Comment: Please make snippet, your code is messy!

Comment: Try changing this line `$("#yolo").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'losers', :locals => {:users=> @users}) %>")` to `$("#yolo").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'losers', :users=> @users}) %>")`

Comment: @Pavan The checkboxes change their value